# symbolization with atos

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsexception

MyApplication creates a personalized crash report using the NSException instance. The app retrieves the callStackSymbols array and adds them to a text file.

If you notice on the crash report, instead of getting a line like this:

> libsqlite3.dylib                  0x30531ce4 0x30506000 + 179428

I'm getting a line like this one

> 29  MyApplication                 0x00059260 MyApplication + 4704

Looks like instead of getting 2 addresses, I get "MyApplication" in the middle.
Atos is not working with the first address.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the symbolicated results, since your app binary contains the debug symbols, so calling `callStackSymbols` can resolve the addresses right away. The only missing part is the line numbers, which isn't possible to get automatically with the symbols being part of the app.

The three number values are: `Address = Base Address + Offset`. This means the first address is enough to get the symbol. The Base address is the start address of the binary/framework. Mostly when symbolication is done, the first address is also changed to be relative to the framework address instead of being absolute. The app binary memory area usually starts at `0x1000`. This can be viewed in a crash reports binary images section, and it can be different to `0x1000` due to new memory features in newer iOS versions.

So for now simply use the give address in the 3rd column and add `0x1000` to the value when invoking atos.

In general I suggest using a framework based on [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/), which will give you all information for a crash report. Including all threads and binary images in a standard crash report format and also works in the App Store.